# UITextField Cursor Not Seen When Active

Tags: uitextfield

When my text field becomes the first responder, somehow the cursor is not seen. I tried changing the tint color of the textfield, but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.
When text field become active, I was making a suggestor tableView's hidden property false. 
For some reason this was what's causing the cursor to be hidden. So I added the line `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(textFieldName)` and magically the issue is resolved.

Man, I spent literally **hours** on this issue. Almost all UX feedbacks included this little but seemingly very important issue.

Hope this helps someone else not waste hours!

Cheers,

Murat